# Endpoints of a 3D line

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How to find the coordinate of the endpoints (A and B) of a line on a surface with known surface normal, center coordinate, and length?
[image]

Comment: Aren't there infinitely many solutions for lines on a surface that are orthogonal to the normal?

Comment: You define a circle on plane. You cannot find $A$ and $B$.. You would need to give a direction to get one value of $A$ and $B$ pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find only upto rotation of $AB$ in tangent plane.

From given normal find unit normal $N$ .

Find two different vectors $ T $ and $B$ so that  dot products $T\cdot N $ and $ B\cdot N $ vanish and find their unit vectors. $ T,B$ need not be perpendicular.

Linear combination vectors $ \lambda N + (1-\lambda)  B$ are in tangent plane, multiply by $AB/2$ for vector length.